# Has FeedbackReceiver been deprecated in Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am working on an Azure IoT Hub project using the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client NuGet package. I have read some documentation about the FeedbackReceiver class for receiving feedback messages, but I am not sure if this class has been deprecated or replaced by a different method. Can anyone confirm if FeedbackReceiver is still a valid class to use for receiving feedback in Azure IoT Hub, or if there is a different recommended method?

Comment: can give the code(or) error (or) what you tried

Answer (score 1):

The **FeedbackReciver** class hasn't been deprecated and is part of the latest version of the SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.feedbackreceiver-1?view=azure-dotnet. Note that it's in the **Microsoft.Azure.Devices** namespace and not the **Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client** namespace - therefore it's intended to be used in your service, not on your device - see the sample referenced below.

The SDK repo includes a sample that shows it in use where an instance is returned by the **GetFeedbackReceiver()** method: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/iothub/service/samples/getting%20started/ServiceClientSample/ServiceClientSample.cs